# Grunt Imagemin on New Files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I'm using Grunt Imagemin to optimize a folder of images. However everytime I run that command, it runs imagemin on ALL of the images. Is there a way to only run grunt imagemin when it detects new changes?

Comment: i have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099367/imagemin-for-gruntjs-used-with-watch-for-grunt-not-properly-watching-my-files

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer):

> Grunt Task for running tasks **if source files are newer only**.

Here you can find a [short tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/tooling/supercharging-your-gruntfile/#toc-buildtime) about how to use it.

After implementing it, you should prepend `newer:` to the imagemin task.

Comment: I tried that in combination with watch - watch: {images:{files: ['my_folder/*.{png,jpg,gif}'], tasks: ['newer:imagemin']}} and it worked. Thx!